# Mac OS X and static boost libs -> std::string fail

Tags: c++, macos, boost, static-libraries

I'm experiencing some very weird problems with static boost libraries (Boost 1.45.0-2 from MacPorts, compiled as fat/universal (x86/x86_64) libraries) under Mac OS X 10.6.6 with GCC 4.5.

The error message is

```
main(78485) malloc: *** error for object 0x1000e0b20: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
[1]    78485 abort (core dumped)
```

and a tiny bit of example code which will trigger this problem:

```
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 3
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  std::cout << boost::filesystem::current_path ().string () << '\n';
}
```

This problem always occurs when linking the static boost libraries into the binary. Linking dynamically will work fine, though.

Even more information:

**gcc versions tested/used:** Apple GCC 4.2.1 (works/runs), MacPorts GCC 4.5.2 (fails)

**flags tested/used:** none, -fPIC, -fPIC -g, -fPIC -g -ggdb3 -gdwarf-2 -O0

**gdb output with MP GCC 4.5.2/any flags of the above:**

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /Users/ionic/crashtest/bin/ctest  Reading symbols for shared libraries .++++++++++++++++++++++.................................................................................................................. done
ctest(80366) malloc: *** error for object 0x100fe6b20: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted. 0x00007fff81a4e616 in __kill ()
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x00007fff81a4e616 in __kill () No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00007fff81aeecca in abort () No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00007fff81a066f5 in free () No symbol table info available.
#3  0x0000000100f763e9 in std::string::_M_mutate () No symbol table info available.
#4  0x0000000100f7644c in std::string::_M_replace_safe () No symbol table info available.
#5  0x0000000100f77edd in std::string::replace () No symbol table info available.
#6  0x000000010000713d in std::string::_M_rep () at /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/basic_string.h:1412
        to = (string &) Cannot access memory at address 0x0
```

Seems like it's working fine with Apple's (quite old) GCC version, but failing badly with the new GCC build by MacPorts.

**otool -L ctest:**

```
./../../bin/ctest:
        /opt/local/lib/gcc45/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.14.0)
        /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 625.0.0)
        /opt/local/lib/gcc45/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.1)
```

<s>I've seen various reports for quite a similar OS X bug with GCC 4.2 and the _GLIBCXX_DEBUG macro set, but this one seems even more generic, as I'm neither using XCode, nor setting the macro (even undefining it does not help. I tried it just to make sure it's really not related to this problem.)</s> Doesn't seem to be related at all to this problem, as the same code is working fine with Apple's GCC.

As Apple's GCC doesn't include any C++0x features yet, I'd indeed like to use the currently stable GCC version.

Does anybody have any pointers to why this is happening or even maybe a solution (rather than using the dynamic library workaround)?

Best regards,

Mihai

Comment: I've updated the post quite a bit and added brand new important information. :)

Comment: What versions of GCC and libstdc++ were used to compile Boost?  If it's what's provided by Apple, I bet it's not binary-compatible with GCC from MacPorts.

Comment: Exactly. I have figured this out a long time ago (actually, the day after writing my last comment.) Will add some answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that Boost has been built using Apple's GCC 4.2.1, whilst I've been building the project using a different compiler.

As I tried to link the static Boost libraries, also the GCC 4.2.1 libstdc++ was put into the binary.
However, at the same time the other GCC version was linking in its libstdc++ and name space problems were inherent, thus the wrong functions were called and the like.

The most simple fix is re-building Boost with your target GCC version and retry the building of your program (ofc. using the self-built Boost.)

Be warned: do not try to change the compiler MacPorts uses for building Boost (it's even not easily possible), or system breakage may occur. Instead, build Boost on your own.

Comment: You can see that otool shows thats its using the libstdc++ in /opt not the system wide one.

Comment: Hi guys.  I'm trying to get the latest stable build of gcc 4.5.2 running on Mac OS 10.6.6 desktop.  Information on building gcc for the latest Mac OS X release is scarce (gcc page lists success for 10.5).  Is MacPorts the way to go ?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, just use MacPorts to compile and install newer GCC releases. They will miss all Apple extensions, but work fine otherwise.

Comment: Same symptom and solution, slightly different problem, but equally applicable: new version of GCC (4.5 -> 4.6) but I had missed recompiling a dependency when rebuilding a project. You get the *oddest* bugs due to ABI differences. Recompiling is easy, however... digging through ASM to find a possible bug in boost sucks. Easy solution FTW.