# Boost.Filesystem create_directories mangles directory name

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I am trying to make a directory using Boost.Filesystem (the directory can be provided by the user, so it may be a path with nested directories; all, some, or none of the directories in that path may exist to start).  When I run the program, a directory is created, but it is not what I asked for; the string containing the path appears to be getting mangled.  I never get the same result twice, but the name of the directory always starts with a colon.

A minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    fs::path path = "junk/morejunk";
    if (!fs::create_directories(path)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create directory " << path << ".\n";
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Running that, I get directories such as `:@K%C5?`, `:%C0)%E0?`, and `:%C0%E9%93?`.

I had some trouble getting Boost to link correctly, but the above program compiles and runs now.  In case it's necessary, some information:

-- I'm using a Mac (OSX 10.9.4)

-- GCC and Boost both installed with MacPorts (Boost with the +gcc49 option)

-- GCC version 4.9.2_1

-- Boost version 1.57.0_1

-- my Makefile looks like

```
CC = /opt/local/bin/g++
FLAGS = -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -lboost_system-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt
driver : driver.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o driver driver.cpp
```

Any suggestions welcome; it's been a while since I've used C++ much, and I'm not very experienced with Boost.

Answer (score 1):

Out on a limb, make sure you save your file as ASCII, latin1 or UTF8.

Otherwise you might have undefined behaviour from incompatible library versions.

You could use `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to get the preferred libraries for boost (the ones which you link against). See also [Is it OK to use DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH on Mac OS X? And, what's the dynamic library search algorithm with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146274/is-it-ok-to-use-dyld-library-path-on-mac-os-x-and-whats-the-dynamic-library-s/3172515#3172515)

Comment: My file is in UTF8.  I didn't mess around with the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, because a lot of sites claim it's not a good idea and I haven't understood why.

It looks like it was the usual Mac OSX issue of different libraries and compilers.  When I deactivated the Macports g++ and used the pre-installed g++, suddenly the problem went away.

Comment: It's not a splendid idea to do "blindly". But it is a key mechanism to do unintrusive deployments (e.g. deploying to machines that might have conflicting versions of libraries installed). the only /better/ way is to use the distro packaged version for everything - but that is usually feasibly only for very large products/very popular opensource

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of mangled directory names. I installed boost using `brew install boost` and  gcc using `brew install gcc6`.

It turns out that the boost was build with the Apple's version of the GCC compiler, and the source file with the original GCC compiler. When I build your source file with Apple's compiler it does work.

Alternatively, build boost yourself with your compiler of choice.

See also the answer on a related question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/4798180/2535529.